# Что использовать для хранения англо-русского словаря на Python?

Tags: python, хранение-данных

Я новичок в программировании, захотел написать кроссплатформенное приложение на python с использованием kivy. В моём приложении мне нужно сделать русско - английский словарь, нужно что бы пользователь мог

1. добавлять новые пары слов
2. удалять старые пары слов
3. чтобы была возможность редактировать существующие пары слов.
4. количество пар слов в районе 2-х тысяч.

Вопрос: в чём лучше всего хранить такой словарь?

Сейчас я решил использовать SQLite, но вспомнил что я когда-то давно использовал CSV, для хранения данных при расчётах. SQLite - это СУБД,  вроде как специализированный инструмент для хранения данных, CSV - это текстовый формат, предназначенный для представления табличных данных. И мне кажется словно бы для моей задачи подходит SQLite, но тогда мне не понятно где используется CSV? 
(Но есть предчувствие что я стреляю из пушки по воробьям)

Comment: Тип данных: обычный словарь. Сохранять: pickle.

Comment: Обычно, языковые словари, имеют связи многие ко многим а не один к одному, поэтому использовать нужно тот инструмент который сможет это сделать =) при количестве 2000 пар - не принципиально где хранить, весь объем данных вполне легко уместить в ОЗУ и не слишком важно как именно хранить(csv\sqlite\nosql\...).

Comment: @Владимир, действительно, что-то я не подумал о многозначности слов:) Можете подсказать о том, с помощью чего это стоит реализовывать? По всей видимости я недооценил сложность задачи:) Можете посоветовать что почитать на тему создания словарей?

Comment: @ВиталийТодоров, врятли я вам что то подскажу по теме, для меня логичным звучало(без чтения спец литературы) - что слова в языках имеют связи многие ко многим, собственно наверное и надо гуглить и читать о разных способах сделать связь многие ко многим =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае намного лучше хранить данные в CSV-файле, если это позволяет устройство

Вы упомянули, что пишите **кроссплатформенное** приложение. Для разных устройств стоит выбирать разные способы хранения данных.

Для **Windows** я бы выбрал CSV, или же MySql, Sqlite.

Для **Android** - определённо CSV, или даже TXT, чтобы не возникало проблем с модулями на других платформах.

<strike>Но для кроссплатформенных приложений всё же стоит выбирать более низкоуровневые языки, нежели Python.</strike>